# Finding Minimum Spanning Tree in O(V+E) when edges have limited values

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

If I have an undirected graph with the edges being only values of 1 or 2, could I find the minimum spanning tree in O(V+E) complexity?

Comment: Hint: modify Prim's algorithm.

Comment: I cant modify the algorethem i need to keep it the same so i think i have to use dfs or bfs ..

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Care to elaborate? I'm not aware of a (properly) linear time implementation of Prim's. Is there some optimization you can do considering the edges are only of weight 1 or 2? Thanks.

Comment: @LayneBernardo If there are only two distinct possible weights, you can make a priority queue where all operations take time O(1) and use it in Prim’s algorithm.

Comment: @templatetypedef Ahh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: I have asked my lecturer about changing what the prim’s algorethem works with and it said you cant do that.. so there must be a way in bfs or dfs..?

Comment: Letting G be the graph, extract the subgraph G1 of 1-edges, find a spanning forest of G1 using DFS, contract G by the connected components of G1 (found using the same DFS), find a spanning forest of the contracted graph, return the union of all forest edges.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks man!